# fprintf debug assertion fail

Tags: c++, fopen, assertions, printf

I have a program that runs correctly if I start it manually. However, if I try to add a registry key to start it automatically during startup, I get this error:

```
Debug assertion failed (str!=null) fprintf.c line:55
```

I tried to add Sleep(20000) before anything happens, but I get the same error.

Here's the code:

```
main()
{
    FILE* filetowrite;
    filetowrite = fopen("textfile.txt", "a+");

    writefunction(filetowrite);
}

int writefunction(FILE* filetowrite) {

    fprintf(filetowrite, "%s", "\n\n");
    ...
}
```

I also tried passing the filename as `char*` and opening it in `writefunction()`, but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried to check that you are actually opening "textfile.txt"?

Comment: It's probably not starting in the folder you think it is.  I doubt C:\Windows\System32\textfile.txt exists :).  (Or whatever the run directory is.)

Comment: Same error with: fopen_s(&filetowrite,"textfile.txt", "a+");

Comment: If I start it manually it opens the file and writes everything it has to.

Comment: Do some proper debugging.  Check the actual path, not relative one, that it's looking for the file.  There's a 99.999999999999% chance the executable is not running with the working directory you think it is.  Alternatively, it may be a permissions error.

Comment: With using full path it works greatly ty all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `fopen` is failing. You should *always* check the return value to see if it works:

```
filetowrite = fopen("textfile.txt", "a+");
if (filetowrite == NULL) {
    // log something, including errno
    exit (1);
}
```

Line 55 of `fprintf.c` in VC++ is:

```
_VALIDATE_RETURN( (str != NULL), EINVAL, -1);
```

where `str` is the `FILE *` argument (nice variable name, Microsoft, what on Earth were you thinking?).

I suspect there may be permissions problems or something similar with trying to run it via the registry (presumably under `Run` or `RunOnce` or as a service).

Once you've figured out what the actual error is, the solution should be easier to produce.

If it's a matter of permissions, you should be able to find that out by using something like `c:\\a\\directory\\i\\KNOW\\i\\can\\write\\to\\textfile.txt` and seeing if it works. Then you can also use that file for logging things like the current directory.

If it simply turns out the "background" starting method is in the wrong directory, change directories as one of your program's first actions.

Answer (score 1):

The following should solve you problem:

1. check if the directory holding your file has the right permission.
2. use real full path when you use fprintf

   ```
    filetowrite = fopen("c:\\textfile.txt", "a+");
   ```
3. run your IDE in Administrator mode (or run you EXE in Administrator mode)