# debug assertion failed fprintf

Tags: c, printf

First I'll start off by saying I have read the link below:

[fprintf debug assertion fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051961/fprintf-debug-assertion-fail)

I'm receiving the same error he/she did, however mine is not due to the same reason. Here's the code, which is in C:

```
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen("C:\ro_apps\IandQ.csv", "w");
fprintf(fp, "%f\n", (j+pTxWbHf110c->cAnalogOutputBuffer)->re);
```

The error I get states:

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: (irrelevant)
File: f:\dd\vctgools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\fprintf.c
Line: 55

Expression: (str != NULL)

I saw in the other link someone had stated using debug to see if the file was even opening before using the fprintf command. Mine doesn't open. Any tips or tricks?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but what sort of shenanigans is `j+pTxWbHf110c->`?

Comment: You need to escape backslashes: `"C:\\ro_apps\\..."`

Comment: Thank you William. And I left out a bit of code as I'm running a for loop Joe, so that's where the j comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filename is wrong. You have to escape every backslash `\`:

```
fp = fopen("C:\\ro_apps\\IandQ.csv", "w");
```

Also you should always check if `fopen` failed:

```
if(fp == NULL){
   perror("Couldn't open file: C:\\ro_apps\\IandQ.csv\n");
   return;
}
```

Comment: Very tempted to -1 for the bad error message.  `perror( path )`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Sorry, I use `fprintf(stderr,...)` and completely forgot about `perror`.

Comment: Thank you for the escape backslash comment, I am still relatively new to C and had never had to use fopen. Not sure how I missed it when I was reading up on it briefly :) I went ahead and added that check and it is indeed failing and I'm not sure why. I know the file name is correct. Are there any special rules with where a file can or cannot be located based on where your solution in VS2010 is located?

Comment: @TZPike05 On Windows 7 you probably don't have rights to write to `C:\anything` without running your application as Administrator.  Try changing the path to something in `C:\Users\yourusername`

Comment: You can use / rather than \ on Windows (just not on the command line).